# Branch.io Dynamic Link For Google Ads Campaign

Tags: google-ads-api, branch.io

We have an iOS/Android app and a landing page. 
We are using branch.io to generate dynamic links. 
We want to create a Google Ads campaign with that link, but we always got final URL mismatch, because of the redirection from the dynamic link to landing Page or Store.
Is there any solution to use dynamic links for google ads campaign? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually occurs when the generated Branch link is used as the Final URL instead of the **Tracking Template**. The Final URL has to be your website link only but the Branch link has to be added in the Tracking Template.

You can find the documentation here: https://docs.branch.io/pages/deep-linked-ads/google-xplatform-search-ads/#ad-creation_1

Please feel free to reach out us at integrations@branch.io in case of any further questions!